# Does evaluating 'else if' take as much CPU time as evaluating 'if' in C?

Tags: c, if-statement

Initial assumption: We will run the following programs 1000 times with argv[1] not being NULL  :

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>


int main( int argc, char *argv[] )  {
 
 if ( argv[1] == NULL ) {
  printf("Usage: a.out argument1");
  exit(1);
}
 else if ( argv[1] != NULL ) {
    
    some_cheap_computation;
    
   
   }

return 0;   
}
```

Will the above code run faster in such case than the following:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>


int main( int argc, char *argv[] )  {
 
 if ( argv[1] == NULL ) {
  printf("Usage: a.out argument1");
  exit(1);
}
 if ( argv[1] != NULL ) {
    
    some_cheap_computation;
    
   
   }

return 0;   
}
```

I've [already learned that the fastest code would make use of](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/C_Programming/Program_flow_control#The_If-Else_statement) `else` instead of `else if`.
Does evaluating `else if` take as much CPU time as evaluating `if` in C?

Comment: You need to check the code that is created in the specific case. Generally using `else if` is something totally different than using `if .. if` or `else`. If the variables in the condition are volatile the compiler must read them again to check second condition. The compiler does not need to optimize and read again even for non volatile conditions. As a result it would also be possible to enter none (in case of `else if`) or both (in case of `if..if..`) `if` blocks.

Comment: Why test for inequality the same thing that you just tested for equality? You only need `else` but because of the `return` under the first condition, you don't even need that.

Comment: This is a typical case of premature optimisation. I assume that `some_expensive_computation` takes much longer than a simple test. But testing for equality and for unequality is pointless anyway, so the whole question is rather pointless.

Comment: BTW: this code does not compile, `exit;` is wrong.

Comment: and in any case, it is better to test `argc` than `argv`.

Comment: @Weather Why is it better to test for argc? Is the evaluation of `if (argc == 0)` faster than the evaluation of `if (argv[1] == NULL)`?

Comment: @Jabberwocky I've already added `#include<stdlib.h>` to both snippets. Now they do compile.

Comment: Because if you were testing for the presence of a *second* argument that method would not work. The `NULL` is a sentinel value, and you would be indexing beyond the array when there isn't a second argument, which is *undefined behaviour*. You would *have* to test `argc` so you might as well be consistent in how you check the arguments, and be idiomatic.

Comment: @JerzyBrzóska adding the includes doesn't make `exit;` correct. It should be e.g. `exit(1);`

Comment: What about no extra `if` or `else`? `if (argv[1] == NULL) { /*...*/ exit(EXIT_FAILURE); } /* expensive computation; */ return 0;`

Comment: Compiled code doesn't work by "evaluating statements"; they don't map in a consistent way to the compiled code; a given bit of machine code doesn't take a constant time to execute; sometimes it can be compiled out completely; and in any event it will take orders of magnitude less time to do this than whatever your `some_expensive_computation;` is, which in turn is probably much faster than a single `printf` (because that's an I/O operation). In short, it doesn't make the slightest bit of sense to be asking the question. Please *learn how to write correct code* first.

Comment: If you actually want to study this kind of thing, and have learned the fundamentals well enough to ask reasonable questions, the best way is probably via a university course. If you just want to make your code perform better then you need to forget every rule of thumb about what "runs faster" than which, study algorithms, learn how to use a profiler, and only after that does it make any sense to consider this kind of micro-optimization. At which point you will mostly be *experimenting* anyway.

Comment: This makes no sense whatsoever. `else if ... ` is equivalent to `else { if ... }` (unless you are disambiguating a nested if).  It is completely analogous to e.g. `x+y` vs `(x+y)`. Neither will run faster. Your link doesn't say anything at all about `else` vs `else if` so you could not have learned that from there. You misunderstood what the text is saying.

Comment: @pmg `if (argv[1] == NULL) { exit(EXIT_FAILURE); } /* expensive computation; */ return 0;` makes sense. My question still remains: whether testing with `else if` uses as much CPU as testing with `if`. I may not have much use of this knowledge other than satisfying my curiosity.

Comment: @Jabberwocky @Karl I already modified my code snippets. Not it is `some_cheap_computation;` . I think it detracts less now from what I intended to be the meat of the question.

Comment: I think a smart compiler will compile all versions to the same machine code... https://godbolt.org/z/zfKvsbje4

Comment: The whole question doesn't make sense with your code. Once you've teste `argv[1] == NULL` it is pointless to test for `argv[1] != NULL`.

Comment: Short answer is : Write your code as you wish, compiler will make it fast for you

Comment: You test argc rather than argv because there's no guarantee for any n (i.e. >argc) that argv[n] is NULL.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It literally makes no difference. The compiler will optimise all versions to the same code. It can see that the second condition is the opposite of the first. This holds true for at least -O1. With -O0 there is zero point in arguing over performance.

See [Compiled version 1](https://godbolt.org/z/seM4b6fE8).

See [Compiled version 2](https://godbolt.org/z/aMK4d1coj).

Both generate this assembly:

```
.LC0:
        .string "Usage: a.out argument1"
main:
        mov     rax, QWORD PTR [rsi+8]
        test    rax, rax
        je      .L6
        movsx   eax, BYTE PTR [rax]
        add     eax, 1
        ret
.L6:
        sub     rsp, 8
        mov     edi, OFFSET FLAT:.LC0
        call    printf
        mov     edi, 1
        call    exit
```

Comment: With `some_cheap_computation` commented out they do not produce the same machine code. **1**.: https://godbolt.org/z/seM4b6fE8 **2**.: https://godbolt.org/z/1G14nfqda

Comment: @JerzyBrzóska You post the same links I provided. The content is therefore identical. If I comment out the return statement, it also produces the same in both cases.

Comment: Apologies, it was done unwittingly. They produce the same machine code indeed.

Answer (score 2):

In theory, we have no idea (and we probably shouldn't care): the C reference documentation only very rarely talks about things like number of cycles for statements and for a good reason, it's **very** architecture dependent.

## On X86

To answer your question, let's test it with some good old A/B testing. I'm not good at writing assembly though and the x86_64 instruction set is way too complicated for me to even try so I asked gcc to compile this program with `gcc -O3 -S` for me:

```
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    int ret = 0;

    if(argc > 1)
    {
        ret += argc + 1;
    }
    else if(argc > 2)
    {
        ret += argc +2;
    }

    return ret;
}
```

and the assembly listing it created is:

```
main:
    xorl    %edx, %edx
    leal    1(%rdi), %eax
    cmpl    $1, %edi
    cmovle  %edx, %eax
    ret
```

I then removed the `else` in the `else if` statement line 12 and asked gcc to recompile the program:

```
main:
    xorl    %eax, %eax
    cmpl    $1, %edi
    jle .L1
    leal    1(%rdi), %eax
    cmpl    $2, %edi
    je  .L1
    leal    2(%rax,%rdi), %eax
.L1:
    ret
```

As you can see, there's some difference between the two listings with the `else if` version being 3 instructions and 1 label shorter. How long would those instructions take? We have no idea, and I mean it. Modern architectures are so complex with things such as pipelines, multiple levels of cache that may need to be cleared, SMTs... Maybe it will take longer than the "if" version on your new AMD Ryzen 9 and it would be the other way around on your old Intel Core 2 Duo, from your perspective as a developer there's virtually no way to know.

## On other architectures

Well, you can test if you want to though but... Do you? From what you just read you probably understand it's not as easy as just saying

> "if else" is faster than "if"

as if it was an universal truth. It depends on so many factors that you really shouldn't care about it. Maybe there's an architecture out there where "if" is 10 times faster than "else if" and you'll actually have a slower program on this architecture, maybe on some very parallelized CPU both will be executed and the result is discarded at the end, taking the exact same time in both cases...

The only industry I know of that actually did CPU optimization on a large scale is the gaming industry: every single PlayStation 2 has the same CPU whether it's the first one ever made or it was bought 5 years later. For game programmers at the time it made sense to optimize for one specific CPU as you **had** to make your game fit on it. Nowadays though you get things like the PS4 with a "Pro" model having a different CPU so even game studios stopped optimizing so much.

## Does it even matter?

I don't think so. As commenters have pointed out under your question you'll probably want to optimize your code and algos first as just a single unneeded assignation could cost you more than those 3 instructions.

Another factor is how your compiler handles your code: modern x86 compilers are very good at understanding your code and will remove as many instructions as possible: you may think my test program above is kinda over-complicated just to test for a 4 characters difference but when I tried to make my program even a tiny bit simpler gcc didn't use conditional jumps at all, it saw a pattern I didn't and made the program go from ~10 instructions to just 5.

## So... What should I do then?

If you want to optimize for a very specific CPU and every single nanosecond matters, do loads of A/B testing about what statements are faster. If you're just a normal programmer trying to make a program work while being as fast as it can try to make your **intent** clear to the compiler, use "else if" if that's what you want your program to do and use "if" if it makes more sense for your program.

This advice works for any other "what is this fastest between those two methods" by the way, use a `switch case` if it makes more sense, use `++var` where is makes sense for your program, the compiler will do its thing anyway

Comment: I don't see how it is architecture dependent when compiler optimization level > -O0 outputs same assembly for OP's code

Comment: @GabrielT that's the thing, it outputs the same assembly listings **on x86**, on some architecture it could be faster to run both codes at the same time and then evaluate the condition to check what should be discarded, it doesn't sound like a very good architecture to me but it **could** exist

Comment: You did not enable optimisations. Un-optimised code is not designed to run fast. Trying to measure something your product is not designed to do is an exercise in futility.

Comment: @n.1.8e9-where's-my-sharem. sorry for retracting my comment, You're actually right, it was unoptised, I don't know why gcc wouldn't let me make the code shorter then, I guess there's some optimization you can't deactivate

Comment: And I think you're both right to be honest, my whole point was how futile this is compared to compiler optimizations and CPUs quirks, I just thought I could go a bit deeper into the "why you shouldn't care" part

Comment: I know unoptimised code when I see it. For reference, [here is optimised code](https://godbolt.org/z/KGW4xhMbb). **My** point is you should never invoke unoptimised code in any discussion about performance, because whatever point you are trying to make, unoptimised code fails to illustrate it.

Comment: @n.1.8e9-where's-my-sharem. you're right, sorry for not seeing it earlier, I modified my answer to include 03 listings

Answer (score 1):

I've made a small simulation to clear out the difference between subsequent `ìf` and usage of `else if`:

Case 1:

```
     if (a==1) { }
else if (a==2) { }
else if (a==3) { }
else if (a==4) { }
else if (a==5) { }
else if (a==6) { }
else if (a==7) { }
else if (a==8) { }
else if (a==9) { }
else if (a==10) { }
```

Case 2:

```
if (a==1) { }
if (a==2) { }
if (a==3) { }
if (a==4) { }
if (a==5) { }
if (a==6) { }
if (a==7) { }
if (a==8) { }
if (a==9) { }
if (a==10) { }
```

Different situations (a being 1, 5, 10):

Amount of checks which are performed:

```
     a|   1|   5|  10
======+====+====+====
Case 1|   1|   5|  10
Case 2|  10|  10|  10
```

So, `else if` is preferable (in order to limit the amount of checks).

Comment: `switch / case` was designed for this situation :-)

Comment: Correct if you disable compiler optimization

Comment: @GabrielT If you disable compiler optimization, you have no business looking at performance.

Comment: Yes that's what I meant, this kind of answer is wrong because the purpose of compiler optimization is not to choose the best between if and else if. OP should just go for the clearer code and compiler optimise

Answer (score 0):

Previous posts have emphasised how your answer will depend on the compiler, and the architecture. Amen to all that. Now, here's a slightly different sort of answer.

Have you ever tried to write an optimiser? I wrote one for an interpreter, not a compiler.  It is the devil of a job: you always think of extra cases you can optimise, but each case has to be checked so it actually performs in all the cases. So, consider the following bit of code...

```
if (x == 0) n = 1;
else if (x == -x) n = 2;
else n = 3;
```

If you are writing a whole sequence of *else if* tests, you might want to arrange the tests so the most likely test finishes first. If your input had a lot more zero numbers than non-zero ones then it may help to put the test for zero at the top, so most cases are dealt with as quickly as possible. You might want to make the more complicated test only happen if the simple one fails to save processing. So the best thing an optimiser can often do is to assume the person who wrote the code should know best.

But the test on the *else if* line is only true if x == 0. You should never get n == 2. A perfect optimiser ought to ignore this test. But if you have a long string of *else if* tests it will need to test that each statement is possible given any combination of any of the previous tests. This is hard to do, and not very rewarding in the general case. So optimisers may perform miracles in other parts of the code, but leave tangles of conditionals alone.